# How to use SQL IN operator in Slick

Tags: sql, slick, play-slick

How do you perform the following SQL operation in Slick:

`select * from tablename where label in ('A', 'B');`

Haven't been able to find in the documentation or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Slick operator is `inSet`.  (I assume `in` collided with something.)

For example:

```
tablename.filter(_.label inSet Set("A", "B")).result
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you give an example of how to write the query using this operator?

Comment: @Geekster `table.filter(r => r.label.inSet(labels)).result`

Comment: `labels` here would be a list like 'A, B'?

Comment: @Geekster -- any `Traversable` will do, so List, Set, Stream, whatever.  And, I don't like nmat's example.  I would write `table.filter(_.label inSet labels).result`

Comment: @Malvolio This works well! Thanks. Could you update your answer with this bit. I will accept your answer then.